# how to remove duplicates from array of dictionary for a specific key

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
{
    distance = "0.03159804520191554";
    rid = 374824705969;
    uuid = "1838346268_374823983610_2016-08-08T07:32:08.679GMT";
},
{

    rid = 374824705969;
    uuid = "1838346268_374823983610_2016-08-08T07:32:08.679GMT";
},
{
    rid = 374824706065;
    uuid = "1838346268_374823983610_2016-08-08T07:32:22.680GMT";
}
```

This is what I got from the array of dictionaries. I want to remove duplicates where rid=374824705969 without using loops.Can any one help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't try anything. As I am new for objective c, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: NSSet is not working for different or multiple no of keys.

Comment: Question: Which one do you remove? The one with `distance`, the one without? Do you need to combine them if needed into one?

Answer (score 0):

Try these one:

```
NSArray *array = @[
    @{
        @"rid" : @374824705969,
        @"uuid" : @"1838346268_374823983610_2016-08-08T07:32:08.679GMT"
    },
    @{
        @"rid" : @374824705969,
        @"uuid" : @"1838346268_374823983610_2016-08-08T07:32:08.679GMT"
    },
    @{
        @"rid" : @374824706065,
        @"uuid" : @"1838346268_374823983610_2016-08-08T07:32:22.680GMT"
    }];


    NSMutableSet *keys = [NSMutableSet new];
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (NSDictionary *data in array) {
        NSString *key = data[@"rid"];
        if ([keys containsObject:key]) {
            continue;
        }

        [keys addObject:key];
        [result addObject:data];
    }

NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Konstantin this work for me but in this we are using loop. What if no. of dictionaries will be large ??

Comment: Then you should use your own class instead of dictionaries and rewrite ```-(NSUinteger)hash``` in it. And then put these objects in NSSet instead of NSArray